# Dividing a list of number by itself

Tags: python, list

The question that I have is trying to find the highest degree of divisibility

I have a list of numbers and I to divide them by themseleves

Example below

```
a = [2,2,5,4,12,64]

2 can be divided by [2,2]
5 can be divided by [5]
4 can be divided by [2,2,4]
12 can be divided by [2,2,4,12]
64 can be divided by [2,2,4,64]

That means the highest degree of divisibility is 4
```

Here is the code the I wrote so far.

````
b = len(a)

for i in range(b):

    c = np.divide(a, a[i])
    print(c)
```
I am wondering how can write the code to output the highest degree of divisibility.

Thanks!
````

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: You can do it using nested loops. Use `if x % y == 0:` to tell if `x` can be divided by `y`.

Comment: split problem to smaller problems and try to resolve these smaller problems - step by step. First you need loop which get value from `a` and use other loop to divide it by all elements from `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
def test():
    
    a = [2,2,5,4,12,64]
    
    maxv = -999
    for i in a:
        counter=0
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if i%a[j]==0:
                
                counter+=1
                
                if counter>maxv:
                    maxv=counter
    print('highest number:',maxv)
    
test()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I am wondering why do we need to have ````maxv = -999```` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers you're checking for divisibility will give the same results (like the two 2's), iterate over the set of unique numbers and then try to divide each number in that set by each number in the original list `a`. Using the modulo operator `%`, each time the remainder is 0, increase the counter for that number and add the final result to a list. Then take the maximum:

```py
a = [2,2,5,4,12,64]

divs = []
for num in set(a):
    count = 0
    for denom in a:  # denominator
        if num % denom == 0:
            count += 1
    divs.append(count)

print(divs)  # to see the count of the divisors
# [4, 2, 3, 1, 4]
print('highest degree:', max(divs))
# highest degree: 4
```

This can be reduced to almost a one-liner using a list comprehension for the outer loop. For the inner 'count'ing loop, use a generator expression like so: in Python, `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` evaluates to `0`. So if we `sum` the number of times that division check is `True`, we get the count:

```py
divs = [sum(num % denom == 0 for denom in a) for num in set(a)]
print('highest degree:', max(divs))
```

And, since we're taking the `max()` of it, we could turn the outer loop into a generator expression as well:

```py
highest = max(sum(num % denom == 0 for denom in a) for num in set(a))
```